# JPA: How to generate entities from another schema?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle, jpa

I have database with tables created for user *A*. User *B* is granted CRUD access to those tables. In SQL queries, user *B* could refer to the tables on the schema *A* using fully qualified name *A.TABLE*. The application will use user *B* to operate on those tables.

However, when I try to generate JPA entity classes for the application using user *B* connection, the JPA wizard doesn't let me select schema *A*, where tables resides. I have ensured the grants are correct by using a fully qualified table name *A.FOO* in the SQL query on user *B* connection.

[image]

I have tried to use synonyms as follows

```
create or replace synonym B.FOO FOR A.FOO;
```

But tables still can't be found by the JPA tool. I wouldn't like to generate tables using user *A* connection either. How to correctly generate entities from different schema?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the following "trick" (basically, a cuckoo in the nest) will work or not, but that's what I used once (not in JPA, though): suppose you start from scratch (i.e. remove that synonym). Then create an empty (`where 1 = 2`) table (in schema B) for table owned by A, using CTAS:

```
create table foo as select * from a.foo where 1 = 2;
```

Now try to do what you're doing - the JPA wizard *should* see the FOO table as it now belongs to B. Once you're done,

```
drop table foo;
create synonym foo for a.foo;
```

and see whether everything works as expected. Good luck!

Comment: I don't know if I should cry or laugh. There has to be another way

Comment: Well, it depends how desperate you are :) Laugh first, then cry, and - if nothing else works, apply what I've written :)